# Date validation helper for mongoid/active model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, date, mongoid

are there any date validation helper for mongoid or active model?
I want to check dates on valid ISO_8601 standard (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Dates) which is not a big deal with mongoids `validates_format_of`. But the date should be in future or depending on the field >= another date (start- and enddate).

My approach would be to check the format with `validates_format_of` and to write my own date validators for my further requirements.

Anyone done that before?

Thanks,
Julian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [validates_timeliness](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness) does complete validation of dates, times and datetimes for Rails 3.x and ActiveModel.

It explicitly supports Mongoid:

```
ValidatesTimeliness.setup do |config|

  # Extend ORM/ODMs for full support (:active_record, :mongoid).
  config.extend_orms = [ :mongoid ]

end
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using validates_timeliness now and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

your approach seems like a good one.  the best way to do this is to break out the validation to its own function.

you can do this like so:

```
class Foo
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :date_time, :type => DateTime
   validate :date_is_ok?

   def date_is_ok
     unless self.date_time.to_i > Time.now.to_i
        errors.add :date_time, "must be in the future"
        return false
     end
     true
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using validates_timeliness for date/time validation now.